# What's the Life Philosophy / Approach analogous to IT DevOps "Blue / Green" Deployments?

Tags: life, analogy

In modern IT, there's the DevOps concept of "Blue / Green Deployments".  Here are some links:

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/blue-green.html
https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html

One of the key concepts is that you don't try to fix an existing (broken) production environment - instead, you focus your efforts on deploying new infrastructure or otherwise replacing the problem.

I was wondering if there's a name/approach to living life like this in general.  For example, if there was an old road bridge (that only had a few years left) - rather than trying to fix it, you would start building a new (replacement bridge), and (once finished) just destroy / remove the old one.  In the meantime there would be no maintenance or other repairs etc. made to the old "production" bridge.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. This site is about philosophy in a more academic sense rather than "life philosophy". And "if it is broken throw it away and get a new one", while it can be the right move on occasion, is a pretty bad life philosophy in general. It is more of a good motto for aggressive marketing in the age of consumerism.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Conifold.  Not saying that it's a good thing - just wondering whether it had a name or not.

Comment: P.S. I am sorry if I'm asking this in the wrong place - but I'm not sure where the correct place for me to be doing so is.  Thanks :)

Comment: English SE usually answers definitional questions, the closest word I can think of is generic [radicalism](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/350579).

Comment: Hmmm - not sure if that's it.  My reading of Generic Radicalism is "Doing More, Sooner, at Greater Cost, and with Greater Potential Disruption".  But sometimes, building a "new bridge" is actually a safer option (that may actually take a lot longer) than trying to fix an older (possibly flawed/inferior) design

Comment: "Sometimes" does not make a life philosophy, a maxim that can not be aspired to regularly is not really a maxim. This is probably why you won't find a match. Even something like perfectionism is supposed to be a regular disposition.

Comment: Very good - thank you @Conifold.  Have been thinking about this for quite some time, useful to have the discussion.  Cheers

Comment: I'd say this is classic software engineering (for which a SE exists). And you are asking about *improving redundancy* (from cursory reading your links). "Single point of failure" would be another cue for google.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Rusi - will ask there

Comment: Ah @Rusi - actually you end up "knocking the old bridge down" (because you know it is going end of life) - so it's not about actually improving redundancy, but more to do with succession planning.  Note that by doing no maintenance on the old bridge, you are actually being less disruptive.  (The bridge doesn't need to be closed for repairs.) . Instead, when you are ready you just cut over to the new one.

Comment: Maybe this isn't a philosophy as such, but a strategic approach to managing the lifecycle of a product.  (It's hard to know where you are supposed to be asking - when you don't really know what it is to start with... Chicken & Egg I guess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Blue/Green approach](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/blue-green.html) to deploy software changes may be analogous to some models that attempt to assist human beings make behavioral changes. Human agents recognize that change is desirable either in their technology or in their own behavior. How to make that desired change when doing so is not easy is what these models attempt to solve.

One model for assisting humans to change their behavior was proposed by James O. Prochaska and Carlo Di Clemente in the 1970s. Here is Wikipedia's description of the [transtheoretical model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transtheoretical_model):

> The transtheoretical model of behavior change is an integrative theory of therapy that assesses an individual's readiness to act on a new healthier behavior, and provides strategies, or processes of change to guide the individual. The model is composed of constructs such as: stages of change, processes of change, levels of change, self-efficacy, and decisional balance.

In the [Blue-Green deployment](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/blue-green.html) that the OP cited there are five stages:

1. [Push an App](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/blue-green.html#push-an-app)
2. [Update App and Push](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/blue-green.html#update-and-push)
3. [Map Original Route to Green](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/blue-green.html#map-green)
4. [Unmap Route to Blue](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/blue-green.html#unmap-blue)
5. [Remove Temporary Route to Green](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/blue-green.html#remove-temp-route)

In the transtheoretical model there are six [stages of change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transtheoretical_model#Stages_of_change):

1. Precontemplation ("not ready") – "People are not intending to take action in the foreseeable future, and can be unaware that their behaviour is problematic"
2. Contemplation ("getting ready") – "People are beginning to recognize that their behaviour is problematic, and start to look at the pros and cons of their continued actions"
3. Preparation ("ready") – "People are intending to take action in the immediate future, and may begin taking small steps toward behaviour change"
4. Action – "People have made specific overt modifications in modifying their problem behaviour or in acquiring new healthy behaviours"
5. Maintenance – "People have been able to sustain action for at least six months and are working to prevent relapse"
6. Termination – "Individuals have zero temptation and they are sure they will not return to their old unhealthy habit as a way of coping

The remaining question is whether the blue-green depolyment model is analogous to the transtheoretical model. If the analogy is weak it should be rejected, but if the analogy is strong enough making the analogy explicit may offer insight for further improvements in these models. I will leave that for the OP to decide.

---

Cloud Foundry Documentation (2019) Retrieved on September 15, 2019, at https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/blue-green.html

Wikipedia contributors. (2019, August 26). Transtheoretical model. In Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. Retrieved 13:48, September 15, 2019, from https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Transtheoretical_model&oldid=912561601

Comment: Thank you @Frank Hubeny - some thoughts there for me to follow up on.  Would up vote but I'm too new!  Brand new to this SE (and actually Philosophy in general). Cheers, Patrick

Comment: @PatrickRynhart Thank you, Patrick. And thank you for the question. I would not have made these connections without it. Best wishes.